# C# and XPath - getting attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm open to all suggestions, but prefer no looping if possible.  I'm trying to get the num-found attribute from this XML into a variable, but it's coming back NULL and I can't figure out why:

xmlStringGoesHere is this below: 
        [image]
Code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStringGoesHere);
int intNumFound = Convert.ToInt32(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/orcid-message/orcid-search-results/@num-found").Value);
```

I'd like to use SelectSingleNode since it's one line of code.  Someone suggested doing this below, but neither one of these work.  Furthermore, is there a way to do this without all the "local-name" crap bloating up the code?

```
object intNumFound = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name() = 'orcid-message']/*[local-name() = 'orcid-search-results']");
object intNumFound = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name() = 'orcid-message']/*[local-name() = 'orcid-search-results']/@num-found]");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there are no elements named `orcid-message` or `orcid-search-results`; the `xmlns` in the XML makes it so you have to qualify those names. Here's how you include namespaces in your query:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStringGoesHere);

var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("o", "http://www.orcid.org/ns/orcid");

var attribute = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(
    "/o:orcid-message/o:orcid-search-results/@num-found", 
    nsMgr);
int intNumFound = Convert.ToInt32(attribute.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStringGoesHere);
int num = Int32.Parse(xdoc.Root.Elements().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "orcid-search-results").Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "num-found").First<XAttribute>().Value);
```